# CSS - Absolute unit that stays the same between devices

Tags: html, css

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480617/is-a-css-pixel-really-an-absolute-unit-that-is-is-1-inch-96px-true), a pixel is not an absolute unit, and I've found this to be the case in practice.

I've also tried using pt, cm and mm but I can't find an absolute unit, I want a unit I can use to specify element sizes that will always stay the same regardless of the screen size or device that is used.

Is there a unit I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

What about using VW and VH to size both fonts and elements?
https://webflow.com/blog/how-and-why-to-use-vh-and-vw-in-webflow