# Google Chrome css width can not display correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome

I met a strange problem.
When I set a div as width: 1.1px, It will display as 1.094px.

[image]

It can correctly display in firefox.

Does any one know how to fix this?

### edit

Addition1: It will display as 1.09px actually.

Addition2: division has the same problem, like 101px's 10% will be 10.09px.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480617/is-a-css-pixel-really-an-absolute-unit-that-is-is-1-inch-96px-true

Comment: @caramba thanks, but it seems not provide an feasible way to resolve it. I'd like to know how to fix it rather than why it happen.

Comment: afaik it will not be possible to fix it with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a min-width to it maybe that'll work!