# rem on mobile and desktop devices?

Tags: html, css, text, responsive-design, typography

I noticed that the font size on mobile and desktop devices are different. I measured the real size of the letter 'T' with a size of 2 rem with a ruler. On my laptop the big 'T' is 6 mm high and on my tablet as well as on my smartphone the 'T' is 4 mm high. I also checked multiple browsers and got the same result.

Shouldn't they be the same height on all devices?

Answer (score 0):

No.

`rem` is relative to the font size of the root element, which has different defaults on different systems.

Answer (score 0):

**rem** is not a fixed measure of font-size like *px*. It is relative to the root HTML element, not its preceding/parent element.

Hope this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#ems_and_rems

Comment: Is this right what [this diagram](http://xahlee.info/js/i/css_reference_pixel.png) shows then? My question is now, why the size is the same on my 10+ inch tablet and on my 5 inch smartphone? Pixel density of my tablet is ~225 dpi and ~428 dpi on the phone.

Answer (score -1):

From [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#absolute-lengths) (CSS Working Group):

> For a CSS device, these dimensions are anchored either
>  by relating the physical units to their physical measurements, or
>  by relating the pixel unit to the reference pixel.

Often, you'll see:

> 1px = 1/96th of 1in

But really it depends on your device. See [Is a CSS pixel really an absolute unit? That is, is 1 inch = 96px true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480617/is-a-css-pixel-really-an-absolute-unit-that-is-is-1-inch-96px-true).