# Why are screen sizes different from actual display resolutions in responsive web design?

Tags: responsive-design, responsive

I'm learning about responsive web design and I'm confused about the difference between screen sizes and display resolutions. When testing the responsiveness of a website in Chrome's responsive mode, I noticed that the screen size listed for the iPhone 12 Pro is 844x392 pixels, while its actual display resolution is 2532 × 1170 pixels. This inconsistency has raised questions about the relationship between screen sizes and display resolutions in responsive web design.

Why aren't display resolutions used as the screen size and vice versa? I'm seeking a detailed explanation to understand the significance of these metrics and their impact on responsive website design. I'm particularly curious about the unit "pixel" in this context and how it represents both the screen size and the display resolution of the same device, despite being dimensionally different (e.g., 844x392 pixels vs. 2532 × 1170 pixels for the iPhone 12 Pro).

I would greatly appreciate any insights, explanations, or resources that can clarify this topic. Thank you in advance for your help in unraveling this matter for someone new to web development and design.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the word "responsive" mean to you?

Comment: _"Why aren't display resolutions used as the screen size and vice versa?"_ - because in 2011 the CSS specification made a major break from the past and refined the `px` (pixel) in terms of the human eye and not physical pixels: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480617/is-a-css-pixel-really-an-absolute-unit-that-is-is-1-inch-96px-true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a CSS pixel really an absolute unit? That is, is 1 inch = 96px true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480617/is-a-css-pixel-really-an-absolute-unit-that-is-is-1-inch-96px-true)